# Regarding Haskell list monoid implementation

Tags: haskell

Reading Haskell Monoid source code, i see this,

```
instance Monoid [a] where
        {-# INLINE mempty #-}
        mempty  = []
        {-# INLINE mconcat #-}
        mconcat xss = **[x | xs <- xss, x <- xs]**
```

i do not understand that **xss**, what is xss? and list generator part is confusing too, xs <- xss, how comes?

update:

list comprehension is easy to understand, but look at code, xss, xs, x, what are relationship among 3 symbols, and why xs <- xss? can i write xss <- xsss?

Comment: The `xss`, `xs`, and `x` values could have any name. It's just a naming convention. `xss :: [[a]]; xs :: [a]; x :: a`

Comment: I actually am confused by this, although not by the list comprehension. My questions are: 1) why define it explicitly like this when `concat` is already in the Prelude and does the same thing 2) what happened to `mappend`? I always thought `mappend` was needed for a `Monoid` instance along with `mempty`, with `mconcat` having a default definition in terms of `mappend`?

Comment: @RobinZigmond - `mappend` has a default implementation of `(<>)` from the `Semigroup` superclass of `Monoid`. The [implementation](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/src/GHC.Base.html#line-290) for list is `(++)`.

Comment: @RobinZigmond As for why to define `mconcat` by hand: you say `concat` is in the prelude and does the same thing, but it does not: the `concat` in Prelude is polymorphic, working on any Foldable. Perhaps GHC inlines and fuses well enough that the polymorphic version is as fast as possible, I don't know, but the explicit list comprehension is at least very clear in what it will do.

Comment: @Lee - thanks, I always forget that `Monoid` instances need to already be `Semigroup`s (until I try to write an instance and the compiler complains :) )

Comment: @amalloy - thanks, I know the version in Prelude is polymorphic but I assumed GHC was able to specialise this to lists in a context where lists are clearly being used. But perhaps it is performance-related, as you suggest, since I imagine finding the right version of the polymorphic `concat` to use would have a little bit of performance overhead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like any Haskell issue we should start by looking at the types. We have `mconcat :: Monoid m => [m] -> m`, which means that to define a Monoid instance for `[a]` we need a function that takes a list of lists and returns a list, that is, `mconcat :: [[a]] -> [a]`. Therefore, `xss` is a list of lists. The expression `[x | xs <- xss, x <- xs]` is a list comprehension. This constructs a list by selecting every possible list `xs` from the list-of-lists `xxs`, and then in turn selecting every element `x` from the list `xs`. The output list consists of all possible values `x`. This essentially means that `mconcat` takes a list-of-lists and returns a list containing every value in every list in the original list-of-lists.

Comment: ,still confusing about that xss, xs, x part, are those 3 symbol has a particular  meaning? what if i do ss from xss , what is that mean?

Comment: @SoftwareWisdom - as @4castle said above, it's just a naming convention, they could have been anything. But `x` is an element of type `a`, `xs` is a list of `a`s, and `xss` is a list of lists of `a`s, so the convention reminds you of the structure.

Comment: @SoftwareWisdom these are just variable names, they could be named `a,b,c` instead. It is however somewhat conventional to use `x` for a list element and `xs` for the list itself (being the "plural" of `x`). By extension, `xss` is a name appropriate for a list-of-lists.